# service vs. systemctl scripts -- which to use

Tags: fedora, systemd

In Fedora we have 'systemctl' and 'service' scripts. It seems that service internally calls `systemctl`. So what is the correct/right way on Fedora to start or stop services -- via `systemctl` or `service` facility? May be there are nuances to keep in mind?

Comment: Debian user, so can't answer for sure, but `service foo start` in debian works whether your init system is systemd or sysvinit or upstart; `systemctl` would likely not work if systemd isn't PID1.

Answer (score 14):

The way to stop/start services in Fedora (later versions) is using `systemctl`.

However, there may be a few services left in `/etc/init.d/` which you could control with the `service` command. You can still control them with `systemctl` as `systemd` automatically maps them to unit files for you.

For example, on my CentOS 7 (Fedora 19 or thereabouts), there is a `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` script which I could control with the `service` command. If I use `systemctl` instead, it still works:

```
# sudo systemctl status network
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2014-11-11 08:21:51 GMT; 2 weeks 1 days ago
```

As you can see, it has been mapped to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` by `systemd` and the `systemctl` command controls it.

I could be so 'last year' and use `service` instead:

```
# service network status
Configured devices:
lo eth0
Currently active devices:
lo eth0 tun0
```

Both work, but note that they do give different results in their `status` commands.

Answer (score 11):

It's typically the case that the `service` scripts are redirected to systemctl (Systemd) scripts so it's basically your preference which you want to use.

#### Example

From my Fedora 20 system.

```
$ service sshd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  sshd.service
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-11-21 09:12:10 EST; 5 days ago
 Main PID: 1095 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1095 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Nov 21 09:12:10 dufresne systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Nov 21 09:12:10 dufresne systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Nov 21 09:12:11 dufresne sshd[1095]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Nov 21 09:12:11 dufresne sshd[1095]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

I generally use both methods, since old habits die hard. But if you're trying to adapt to the Systemd world, I'd continue to force myself to do things using `systemctl` if possible.

Also Systemd brings everything that you used to do with `chkconfig` and `service` under one command, `systemctl`, so I generally find that easier to cope with in the long run.

This cheatsheet on the Fedora project's website is helpful in making the switch.

[image: ss1]

Incidentally, the answer to your original question is answered in a footnote on that page:

> Note that all /sbin/service and /sbin/chkconfig lines listed above
>   continue to work on systemd, and will be translated to native
>   equivalents as necessary. The only exception is chkconfig --list.

#### References

- [SysVinit to Systemd Cheatsheet](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet)