# Use service or systemctl to control openvpn daemon on boot?

Tags: openvpn, services

I'm working on a debian-based system and am still learning about [systemctl vs service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170068/service-vs-systemctl-scripts-which-to-use), but am trying to use my `openvpn` configuration as a use-case for working through this.

In my current setup, I'm really confused as to how `openvpn` appears to be starting on boot and how to manage them.

On boot, these are the `openvpn` processes that have been started:

```
> ps aux | ag 'openvpn'
nobody     952  0.0  0.0   5800  1108 ?        Ss   13:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
root      1537  0.0  0.1   6088  2544 ?        Ss   13:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --auth-nocache --config /root/.vpn_conf/pia.ovpn
```

I still don't know what's controlling these to start on boot.

The first proc is the server (which I wish to disable), and the other is the client which I wish to keep and continue to use.

My understanding is that one can use `systemctl` to list all services:

```
> systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | ag 'openvpn'
openvpn.service                               disabled
openvpn@.service                              disabled
```

What are the differences between these two? Are these the two services controlling the processes above? If they are disabled, why are they still starting on boot?

If I try and use `service` to get the status of `openvpn`, I get:

```
> service openvpn status
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-02-19 13:29:51 PST; 18min ago
  Process: 936 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 936 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/openvpn.service

Feb 19 13:29:51 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service
```

Which prompts me to ask:

If there are two entries in systemctl for openvpn, what is the second one called when using `service openvpn_2nd? status`?

Just in case, there is a `/etc/init.d/openvpn` script.

Any insight into some of the questions above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What distro are you running?

Comment: DietPi w/ Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) Linux 3.14.79+

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OpenVPN is not the best place to start if one is learning systemd, because OpenVPN is not a simple service.

OpenVPN is a *templatized service* under systemd.  The *service units* are named `openvpn@config.service`, all derived from a single *service unit file* named `openvpn@.service`.  So you are starting your `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` instance with

```
systemctl start openvpn@server.service
```

and having it auto-start on bootstrap with

```
systemctl enable openvpn@server.service
```

Obviously, you stop and disable it with the analogous commands.

This is not what is running your OpenVPN client, though.  To locate the service unit for that, one can locate the unit name from the control group name, by running

```
systemd-cgls /
```

The non-template `openvpn.service` is explained in the commentary at the top of its service unit file.  It is something else that, again, makes this a more complex thing to learn as a novice's first experience of systemd.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206490/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378824/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/640026