# Fedora 33 - Run command or script at startup

Tags: fedora, startup

In 2020 (last day today too), Fedora 33, what is the ideal way to run a command or script at startup?

I am asking this again because over the years I have seen several different ways of doing it, some of which are now obsolete, so in 2020, what is the ideal way to do this?

Comment: I don't keep much history in my head, but according to Wikipedia, "In May 2011 Fedora became the first major Linux distribution to enable systemd by default", which seems to be Fedora 15.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170068/117549 ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller think that's a different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating my own `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`.
I'm running Fedora Cinnamon Edition, not sure if this works in other distributions.

Example: Create a file named **discord-desktop.desktop** with the following content. On the restart, discord will start minimized.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Discord Desktop
Comment=Discord Desktop for Linux
Exec=flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord --start-minimized
Type=Application
```

Comment: Not useful if you're not running a desktop environment.

Comment: I'm not sure running a command at desktop login counts as "run a command or script at startup".

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the command in root user's crontab with @reboot directive, i.e.

```
@reboot /root/myscript.sh
```

It's a quick and easy way to put small, quick commands to run at startup.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a systemd unit
- put it into /etc/rc.d/rc.local (that's a file not a directory) and enable it:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871 ?

Comment: It **perfectly** works for me on a number of PCs and servers. Also it's one place you can easily remember. If you don't like it, create a systemd unit.